# Como comprobar si ya existe un archivo con el mismo nombre y si es asi, agregarle al final "Archivo (2),Archivo (3),Archivo (4),..." en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero comprobar si el archivo ya existe y si es el caso, entonces añadirle al final algo como "Archivo (2),Archivo (3),Archivo (4),..." como lo hace Windows al guardar algo, y por lo tanto, que no se sobrescriba.

Comment: Utiliza `os.path.exists` para comprobar si el archivo existe. Puedes utilizar un bucle que vaya comprobando si el nombre que vas a asignar al archivo ya existe, y en ese caso asignar un nombre distinto.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza la librería `path` para que resulte más fácil, controla si el archivo existe con `exists` y con un `while` lo sigues intentando al infinito mientras incrementas el número en el nombre del archivo. A continuación un ejemplo:

```
from os import path as osPath

def check_file(filePath, fileName):
    """ Pasar como parametros: directorio de archivo y nombre de archivo completo """

    if osPath.exists(osPath.join(filePath, fileName)):
        numb = 1
        while True:
            # Separa el nombre del archivo de su extensión colocando el numero en el medio (al final del nombre)
            newName = "{0}_{2}{1}".format(*osPath.splitext(fileName) + (numb,))

            # Si existe un archivo con ese nombre incrementa el numero
            if osPath.exists(osPath.join(filePath, newName)):
                numb += 1
            else:
                # Devuelve el nombre modificado si el archivo existe
                return newName
    # Devuelve el nombre original si el archivo no existe
    return fileName
```